# JRE crash randomly when creating a new database with H2

Tags: java, h2, java-11

My application crashes randomly on the first start when the (H2) database is created.

It crashes:

- "a lot" on windows 10 with a jdk11
- "a little" on windows 10 with a jdk8
- never on linux

I have no clue of why this crash occurs neither of course on how to fix it. Upgrading to the latest jdk11 doesn't fix anything, using another build of openjdk (amazon, adoptopenjdk) doesn't fix anything neither.

An example of a crash log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000, pid=18092, tid=52220
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (11.0.8+10) (build 11.0.8+10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM AdoptOpenJDK (11.0.8+10, mixed mode, serial gc, windows-x86)
# Problxxxic frame:
# C  0x00000000
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Xms128M -Xmx512M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -Dkaraf.startLocalConsole=true -Dkaraf.startRemoteShell=true --add-reads=java.xml=java.logging --add-exports=java.base/org.apache.karaf.specs.locator=java.xml,ALL-UNNAMED --patch-module=java.base=lib/endorsed/org.apache.karaf.specs.locator-4.2.9.jar --patch-module=java.xml=lib/endorsed/org.apache.karaf.specs.java.xml-4.2.9.jar --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.xml.dom/org.w3c.dom.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.url.rmi=ALL-UNNAMED -Dkaraf.instances=C:\DEV\RUN\distrib-xxx-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\..\instances -Dkaraf.home=C:\DEV\RUN\distrib-xxx-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\.. -Dkaraf.base=C:\DEV\RUN\distrib-xxx-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\.. -Dkaraf.etc=C:\DEV\RUN\distrib-xxx-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\..\etc -Dkaraf.log=C:\DEV\RUN\distrib-xxx-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\..\data\log -Dkaraf.restart.jvm.supported=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\DEV\RUN\distrib-xxx-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\..\data\tmp -Dkaraf.data=C:\DEV\RUN\distrib-xxx-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\..\data -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\DEV\RUN\distrib-xxx-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\..\etc\java.util.logging.properties org.apache.karaf.main.Main

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9850H CPU @ 2.60GHz, 12 cores, 47G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17763 (10.0.17763.1339)
Time: Fri Sep 11 16:06:48 2020 Paris, Madrid (heure d?�t�) elapsed time: 5 seconds (0d 0h 0m 5s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x06c4d400):  JavaThread "Start Level: Equinox Container: 660fe646-fc21-4287-95c2-97d61c8330a6" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=52220, stack(0x07470000,0x074c0000)]

Stack: [0x07470000,0x074c0000],  sp=0x074baf4c,  free space=299k
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.readFully(JI)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+1
j  org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readStoreHeader()V+14
j  org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(Ljava/util/Map;)V+663
j  org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open()Lorg/h2/mvstore/MVStore;+8
j  org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(Lorg/h2/engine/Database;Lorg/h2/mvstore/MVStore$Builder;Z)V+7
j  org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(Lorg/h2/engine/Database;)Lorg/h2/mvstore/db/MVTableEngine$Store;+231
j  org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore()Lorg/h2/pagestore/PageStore;+19
j  org.h2.engine.Database.open(IILorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;)V+627
j  org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(IIZLorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;)V+5
j  org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Lorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;Ljava/lang/String;)V+698
j  org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Lorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;ZZLjava/lang/String;)Lorg/h2/engine/Session;+145
j  org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Lorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;)Lorg/h2/engine/Session;+54
j  org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Lorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;)Lorg/h2/engine/Session;+2
j  org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Lorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;)Lorg/h2/engine/Session;+4
j  org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Lorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;)Lorg/h2/engine/SessionInterface;+2
j  org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(Z)Lorg/h2/engine/SessionInterface;+98
j  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(Lorg/h2/engine/ConnectionInfo;Z)V+41
j  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+11
j  org.h2.Driver.connect(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+59
j  com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection()Ljava/sql/Connection;+12
j  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection()Ljava/sql/Connection;+33
j  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry()Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolEntry;+5
j  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry()Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolEntry;+1
j  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast()V+20
j  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig;)V+128
j  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection()Ljava/sql/Connection;+100
```

Comment: Maybe the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23779451/10871900)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use JNI and H2 doesn't have any native code either.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that reproduces the H2 crash, so we have some idea of what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Also it looks like the stack dump is truncated. Is that ALL of it?

Comment: A JRE fatal error like this indicates either a bug in the JRE or a bug in JNI code being invoked by the JRE.  Does this look useful [Input/Output Error in org.h2.store.FileStore.readFully #1884](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1884)?  I found that quite easily with a search on `h2 database exception_access_violation FileStore`.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks but this issue is unrelated to my question. no jre crash, just io error because of the users is using incompatible options.